# If variable is defined set variable, if not defined set null

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to set a variable if the variable is defined but if it's not defined, set it to `nil`.

```
def change(cursor:)
end
```

I used:

```
change(cursor: cursor || nil)
```

But I am getting this error:

```
NameError: undefined local variable or method `cursor'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just enter `nil` as the default value.

```
def change(cursor: nil)
  "cursor = #{cursor.nil? ? 'nil' : cursor }"
end

change(cursor: 'cat') #=> "cursor = cat"
change                #=> "cursor = nil"
```